# C++11 Uniform initialization for constructor and operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I have T class and Table that uses T for construction parameter.

```
struct T {
    string name;
    long value;
};

class Table {

public:
    T a, b, c;

    Table(T a, T b, T c) {
        cout << "From constructor: " << a.name << endl;
        this->a = a; this->b = b; this->c = c;
    }
    Table& operator=(const Table& a) {
        cout << "In op=: " << a.a.name << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I also have an example function trying to invoke constructor and = operator.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    Table phone_numbers {
        { "Donald Duck", 2015551234 },
        { "Mike Doonesbury", 9794566089 }, 
        { "Kell Dewclaw", 1123581321 }
        };
    Table phone_numbers2 = {
        { "Donald Dog", 2015551234 },
        { "Mike Doonesbury", 9794566089 }, 
        { "Kell Dewclaw", 1123581321 }
        };

}
```

However both of them invokes only the constructor.

```
From constructor: Donald Duck
From constructor: Donald Dog
```

What might be wrong? How to invoke = operator in this case?

Comment: The `operator=` is used to assign a new value to an already initialized object. Although your second example looks like it would use the=-operator the c++ standard actually defines its semantics as  initialization instead of assignment. If you would add an additional line `phone_numbers2=phone_numbers;`, that line would use the assignment operator.

Comment: This is quite a classic misconception... I am actually baffled that there is no obvious dupe in the related section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator=` is used for assignment, not initialisation. To provoke that, you'll have to assign to an already existing object.

```
Table t = {blah, blah};   // initialisation
t = {wibble, wobble};     // assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

**8.5 Initalizers [dcl.init]**

> A declarator can specify an initial value for the identifier being
> declared. The identifier designates a variable being initialized. The
> process of initialization described in the remainder of 8.5 applies
> also to initializations specified by other syntactic contexts, such
> as the initialization of function parameters with argument expressions
> (5.2.2) or the initialization of return values (6.6.3).
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     brace-or-equal-initializer
>     ( expression-list )
>
> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>     = initializer-clause
>     braced-init-list
>
> initializer-clause:
>     assignment-expression
>     braced-init-list
>
> initializer-list:
>     initializer-clause ... opt
>     initializer-list , initializer-clause ... opt
>
> braced-init-list:
>     { initializer-list , opt }
>     {}
> ```

The way you have constructed `phone_numbers2` is using the second initialization syntax.